# How has review beta affected flagging?

Tags: discussion, flags, review

Stack Overflow got [new moderators in June](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134509/june-2012-community-moderator-election) because there were *"over 1,300"* flags a day.

I used to contribute to this, but since the new review queues the amount of flags I raise has significantly decreased.

Are there any statistics on how the new review queue has affected the flagging rates across Stack Exchange? Has it decreased from the Stack Overflow high?

Also, less likely I know, but has the location which flagging comes from changed? I.e., are more flags received from the *"Low Quality"* queue instead of *"Late Answers"*?

Comment: At a glance, it looks like we've averaged 1570 flags / day over the last quarter on Stack Overflow, and 1620 flags / day over the last month. That seems to indicate that things have been pretty consistent over the last three months as the review system has been updated. More granular stats over a longer term might be needed to come to a better conclusion, though.

Comment: Thanks @BradLarson, it does appear that not much has happened... Maybe I'm just a lazy flagger and picked the low hanging fruit that someone else would have got anyway.